# How to write handler for Error queues in NServiceBus Saga?

Tags: handler, msmq, message-queue, nservicebus, saga

I have a situation where the Maxtries in my MSMQ is 5. After 5 times nservicebus sends the message to the Error que that I have defined. Now I want to perfomr some further action when this happens (I have to update status of some processes to Error)
Is it possible to write a handler in my Saga class to read these error queues?

Thanks in Advance
Haris

Answer (score 2):

If your are using 2.x you may want to consider writing a separate endpoint where the error queue is its input queue.  The downside to this is that the messages will come off the queue.  Assuming you still want to store them, you'll have to push them off to a database or some other type of storage.

You could also write a Saga that polls the error queue to check for messages and updates the appropriate status.  After each time you check the queue, you would need to request another Timeout.

In 3.0, you have more control over the exceptions, and can implement your own way to handle the errors.  If you implement the interface IManageMessageFailures, you can do your work there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think we will install NServiceBus 3.0 first and then see whats the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solutions provided by Adam, you can subscribe to events raised by ServiceControl which are raisesd when a messages is sent to the errorqueue. See the official documentation about this here: http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/contracts

Another approach would be the notification API as described here: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/subscribing-to-error-notifications. It allows you to subscribe to certain events (not event messages) like "MessageSentToErrorQueue" directly on the endpoint, so you wouldn't need to consume the error queue.